# Accessing COM from .Net Core outside process

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, com, com+

I'm trying to create a COM object using Activator.CreateInstance() that is attached to a specific process.
When I have only one process everything is working fine, but now I am trying to create one object per process.

```
Process process1 = Process.Start("exePath", arguments);
Process process2 = Process.Start("exePath", arguments);

var instance1 = Activator.CreateInstance(objType); // want to attach process1
var instance2 = Activator.CreateInstance(objType);

//...some code here

instance1 .GetType().InvokeMember("TEST", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, instance1 , 
                new object[5]
                {
                    "TEST","TEST",null, "111", result
                }); // need to run it in process1

instance2 .GetType().InvokeMember("TEST", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, instance2, 
                new object[5]
                {
                    "TEST","TEST",null, "111", result
                }); // need to run it in process2
```

The problem is , that I could not find a way to specify in which process to run a function. Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance` doesn't work the way you think it does.  It creates instances of .NET types, not COM objects, and it creates them in the current process context.  What you're probably looking for is some form of Remote Procedure Call (RPC).

Comment: According to this https://supportline.microfocus.com/documentation/books/nx50ws03/dmcwiz.htm, a COM server application can be run in one of three ways: Out-of-process, In-process,Remote. I want to run in Out-of-process way and specify a process, I have multiple instances of application opened

Comment: Sure.  You just can't do it with `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Comment: Activator.CreateInstance can create a COM object, but only the ones registered on the machine, like this for example: `Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application"))` which works on Windows because Shell.Application is a registered out-of-process COM object. It cannot connect to any random exe/process.

Comment: And how can I do it? I don't have a source code of application which contains function I want to run

Comment: You can only consume COM objects that exists, ie: that the developer has exposed/documented to you. Most exe don't have COM APIs. If they have, you're supposed to know that.